# Android - Back Button From Send-intent Closes Application in fragment

Tags: android

I'm using share option to share app details.After pressing share button sharing dialog appears, but if i press the back button, the whole application exits!I want to close sharing dialog only....please help

this is my code

```
 public class ItemViewerFragment extends Fragment {  

 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "haii" );
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sample  " );
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample ");

           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share via"));
    }
    });
     }
```

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode).
and then collect result using onActivityResult() method.
This may help you.

Comment: How to give the back press function inside that?